# Extracting features from video

Tags: machine-learning, video-processing, feature-extraction

I am working on my graduation project, which is an AI model to evaluate oral presentation skills based on body language and audio features.
I don't know how I can extract body language features (pointing at slides, keeping hands on the upper body). I need a way -software or python library- to count how many times the presenter points at the slides and a way to count how many times his hands go to his lower body.
If you have any ideas other than counting the number of times, I would love to hear your thoughts

we have rubrics that evaluate the presenter but we have no idea how to extract features Automatically